# Converting string to number in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been trying to convert the following to number:

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-votevalue="1">
    <strong>1</strong>
</button>
```

```js
var votevalue = parseInt($(this).data('votevalue'));
```

I've also tried `Number()` but I'm still getting `NaN` when checking the result. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the complete code:

```
<div class="span7" id="button-group">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-votevalue="1"><strong>1</strong></button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-votevalue="2"><strong>2</strong></button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-votevalue="3"><strong>3</strong></button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-votevalue="4"><strong>4</strong></button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-votevalue="5"><strong>5</strong></button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-votevalue="6"><strong>6</strong></button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-votevalue="7"><strong>7</strong></button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-votevalue="8"><strong>8</strong></button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-votevalue="9"><strong>9</strong></button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-info" data-votevalue="10"><strong>10</strong></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#button-group button').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var votevalue = parseInt($(this).data('votevalue'));
        var filename = $('.mainimage').data('filename');
        var votes = parseInt($('.mainimage').data('numvotes'));
        var totalscore = parseInt($('.mainimage').data('totalscore'));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php/?category=vote',
            data: {
                "votevalue": votevalue,
                "filename": filename
            },
            success: function() {
                votes++;
                alert(votes);
                var average = ((totalscore + votevalue) / votes);
                $('#vote-incremenet').html(votes);
                $('#display-average').html(average);
                $('#display-average').show();
                $('#button-group button').each(function(){
                    $(this).unbind('click');
                });
            }
        }); // end ajax
    }); // end click
}); // end each
```

Comment: What does `this` refer to in the this context?

Comment: What you have will work fine, so I can only assume that `this` does not refer to what you expect. Also, don't forget the radix argument to `parseInt`!

Comment: do you want the value of the data-votevalue property or the text inside the <strong></strong> tags?

Answer (score 107):

It sounds like `this` in your code is not referring to your `.btn` element. Try referencing it explicitly with a selector:

```
var votevalue = parseInt($(".btn").data('votevalue'), 10);
```

Also, don't forget the radix.

Comment: I get the correct string when I dont try parsing the variable. So this referece to right object. I posted the complete code in my original post. Maybe you could take a look.

Comment: The problem must lie elsewhere in your code then, because the `parseInt(votevalue)` section works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fVJRL/

Answer (score 60):

You can use [parseInt(string, radix)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert string value to integer like this code below

```
var votevalue = parseInt($('button').data('votevalue'));
​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8sBpk/)

Comment: can't trust parseInt() tried "1,633" it returns "1".

Comment: Use parseFloat to convert string to float.

Answer (score 32):

Although this is an old post, I thought that a simple function can make the code more readable and keeps with jQuery chaining code-style:

```
String.prototype.toNum = function(){
    return parseInt(this, 10);
}
```

can be used with jQuery:

```
var padding_top = $('#some_div').css('padding-top'); //string: "10px"
var padding_top = $('#some_div').css('padding-top').toNum(); //number: 10`
```

or with any `String` object:

```
"123".toNum(); //123 (number)`
```

Comment: I think your answer is excellent, the only good solution.  parseInt or parseFloat doesn't work well If the value is empty "", then I still get NaN. However, I use your solution and add if(!$.isNumeric(this)){ this =0; }, solve everything.

Answer (score 12):

For your case, just use:

```
var votevalue = +$(this).data('votevalue');
```

There are some ways to convert string to number in javascript.

The best way:

```
var str = "1";
var num = +str; //simple enough and work with both int and float
```

You also can:

```
var str = "1";
var num = Number(str); //without new. work with both int and float
```

or

```
var str = "1";
var num = parseInt(str,10); //for integer number
var num = parseFloat(str); //for float number
```

DON'T:

```
var str = "1";
var num = new Number(str);  //num will be an object. typeof num == 'object'
```

Use parseInt only for special case, for example

```
var str = "ff";
var num = parseInt(str,16); //255

var str = "0xff";
var num = parseInt(str); //255
```

Answer (score 8):

You should just use "+" before `$(this)`. That's going to convert the string to number, so:

```
var votevalue = +$(this).data('votevalue');
```

Oh and I recommend to use `closest()` method just in case :)

```
var votevalue = +$(this).closest('.btn-group').data('votevalue');
```

Comment: Welcome @expoz - note hit {} in the editor to format a code section, or use 4 spaces in front of code line. Plus you can use single quote ` around code to mark code or package commands e.g. `closest()`,

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just an exploitation of JavaScript's poor type management. That doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

var string = 123 (is string),

parseInt(parameter is string);

```
var string = '123';

var int= parseInt(string );

console.log(int);  //Output will be 123.
```

Comment: add details to your answer ?

Comment: Exactly the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12839661), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12839623) for that matter.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like `this` is referring to something else than you think. In what context are you using it?

The `this` keyword is usually only used within a callback function of an event-handler, when you loop over a set of elements, or similar. In that context it refers to a particular DOM-element, and can be used the way you do.

If you only want to access that particular button (outside any callback or loop) and don't have any other elements that use the `btn-info` class, you could do something like:

```
parseInt($(".btn-info").data('votevalue'), 10);
```

You could also assign the element an ID, and use that to select on, which is probably a safer way, if you want to be sure that only one element match your selector.

Answer (score 4):

You can adding a `+` before the string without using parseInt and parseFloat and radix, Simply

sample:

```
var votevalue = +$('button').data('votevalue');

alert(typeof(votevalue));
```

Answer (score 0):

`var votevalue = $.map($(this).data('votevalue'), Number);`

Comment: it is recommended to provide more context to your answer. Review the guide on how to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer