# Jquery number increment to <p> tag

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a variable that holds the main value of the paragraph tag as seen here:

```
<button id="button">random words</button>
   <p id="inc">0</p>
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button').on("click", function(){
          var oldVal = $("#inc")
          $('#inc').text( oldVal + 1)
        });
       });
   </script>
```

How do I turn the '#inc' into a number so i can do a + 1 increment?

Comment: See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/wf0mskrb/). 1. Get the innerText of `<p>`. 2. Convert it to integer 3. Increment by one 4. Update new value

Comment: `var oldVal = $("#inc").text()`, then `parseInt(oldVal)`

Comment: It looks like this needs the parseInt function. Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839567/converting-string-to-number-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback text function to accept old text and modify it with new.

You would also need to parse the old value into integer for incrementing it:

```
$('#button').on("click", function(){
      $('#inc').text(function(i,oldVal){
         return parseInt(oldVal,10) + 1 ;
      });
 });
```

### Working Demo

Comment: this worked, but for what im trying to do, i want to be able to add maybe + 10 to the variable oldVal when i click another button. so how would i incorporate that?

Comment: You would change `1` to `10` or any number by which you want to increase the count

Answer (score 0):

`$("#inc")` returns a jQuery obeject not its content, you can use .text() to get its content then increment it. Note that `.text()` will return a string value so you need to convert that to a numeric value before trying to add 1

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').on("click", function() {
    $("#inc").text(function(i, text) {
      return +text + 1 || 0
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">random words</button>
<p id="inc">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code with below code you will get what you want

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button').on("click", function(){
          var oldVal = parseInt($("#inc").text());
          $('#inc').text( oldVal + 1)
        });
       });
   </script>
```

Actually there is single mistake in your code which is

`var oldVal = $("#inc")` must be replace by 
`var oldVal = parseInt($("#inc").text());`